# hasMany relation: including from the other direction

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

Say I have the next model:

```
user.json:
{//...
    "relations":{
        "invoices": {
            "type": "hasMany",
            "model": "Invoice",
            "foreignKey": "receiverId"
        },
    }
//...
}
```

A.k.a. a user might have many invoices. This code adds the field receiverId to the invoice model.

Now I want to get a list of invoices including their receivers. How can I do that?

```
Invoice.find({include: "reciever"})
```

Or

```
Invoice.find({include: "user"})
```

Did not work, returned: "Relation \"receiver\" is not defined for Invoice model" error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define [belongsTo](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/BelongsTo+relations) relation in your Invoice model.

invoice.json:

```
{//...
    "relations":{
        "receiver": {
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "model": "Receiver"
        },
    }
//...
}
```

Then you can query your model like this:

```
Invoice.find({include: "receiver"}, function(data){ 
   console.log(data);
});
```