# Loopback Models Not Updating - Loopback: Error: Relation "chatroomID" is not defined for ChatMessage model

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, has-many, strongloop, relation

I've looked at the documentation and github issues.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasMany-relations.html

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/76

[hasMany relation: including from the other direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840146/hasmany-relation-including-from-the-other-direction)

I couldn't put my finger on why I was getting the error:`Error: Relation "chatroomID" is not defined for ChatMessage model`

It seems that even though I correctly edited my json, my chatroom model isn't updating (as seen in the REST explorer)

[image]

but chatmessage did manage to update

[image]

---

chat-message.json

```
{
  "name": "ChatMessage",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "relations": {
      "ChatRoom": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "ChatRoom",
        "foreignKey": "chatroomID"
      },

...
```

chat-room.json

```
{
  "name": "ChatRoom",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "relations": {
      "chatMessages": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "ChatMessages",
        "foreignKey": "chatMessagesID"
      }
    }
  },
...
```

In controller:

```
function getMsgs() {
  // http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Include-filter.html
  return (
    ChatMessage.find({
      "filter": {
        "include": {
            "relation": "chatroomID",
            "scope": {
              "include": ["ChatRoom"]
            }
        }
      }

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bidi relations the foreign key should the same.

Also notice that you set the model of relation wrong. It is `ChatMessage` not `ChatMessages` (the 's')
Change like this :

```
//chat-room.json
{
  "name": "ChatRoom",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "relations": {
      "chatMessages": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "ChatMessage",
        "foreignKey": "chatroomID"
      }
    }
  },
...
```

But the error you got is because of including not defined relation, you dont have `chatroomID` relation. You have `chatMessages` relation.

So change it like :

```
ChatRoom.find({
      "filter": {
        "include": {
            "relation": "chatMessages"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Did exactly that, still have error: `Unhandled error for request GET /ChatMessages?filter=%7B%22include%22:%7B%22relation%22:%22chatMessages%22%7D%7D: Error: Relation "chatMessages" is not defined for ChatMessage model`

Comment: @NatuMyers Ah sorry. My bad. The model that be called is `ChatRoom` not `ChatMessage`. I updated my answer. That is another problem in code that you called on a wrong model